# Many to many objects relations in Java Google App Engine

Tags: java, database, google-app-engine, entity-relationship

Maybe I misunderstood this but from what I read I may have several problems creating many to many objects relations in the data store. So I hope I am wrong. Can anyone provide me with ideas on realizing such a system on GAE/J?

What I need is many students can have many files (meaning `Student A` can have `File A` and `Student B` can have `File A` while `Student A` also can have N other different files that he may or may not share with other students). How can I implement a relatively simple DB model for Google App Engine (And please provide how to implement a "get all student files" method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/appengine/docs/java/datastore/relationships.html) is the documentation on relationships for Google App Engine.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

The link Michael provided is to the French documentation.    [Here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html) is the English version.